# Exercise with tensor product base change

Tags: galois-theory, tensor-products

I'm refreshing my knowledge of Galois theory and thinking about Galois extensions and splitting fields. Suppose that $k$ is a ground field, $P$ is some polynomial of degree $n$ with a splitting field $K$, and $K_j$ are intermediate fields ($K_1=k$, $K_2=k[x]/P$ and so on).

My hypothesis is that $K\otimes_k K \simeq K \otimes_{K_{n-1}} K$.

I think that it can be deduced straightforward from base change property of tensor product ($A\otimes_C B \simeq (A\otimes_C D)\otimes_D B$), but some problem appears.

$$K\otimes_{K_{n-1}}K_n \simeq (K\otimes_{K_{n-1}} K_{n-2})\otimes_{K_{n-2}}K_n$$
and I have no idea how to proceed to $K\otimes_k K$ from this step.

It will be great if anybody would tell me is it really true and, if it is, help me to finish proof.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question years later and get this off the unanswered queue, this will be the case if and only if $k\to K_{n-1}$ is an isomorphism.

Recall that if $L/K$ is a field extension, and $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional $L$-vector spaces, then we have
$$
\dim_L(V\otimes_L W) = \dim_L(V)\dim_L(W)
$$
and
$$
\dim_K(V) = [L:K]\dim_L(V).
$$

Let $[K_{n-1}:k] = d$. We have
$$
\deg_k(K\otimes_{K_{n-1}} K) = d\deg_{K_{n-1}}(K\otimes_{K_{n-1}}K) = d[K:K_{n-1}]^2,
$$
while
$$
\deg_k(K\otimes_k K) = [K:k]^2 = ([K:K_{n-1}][K_{n-1}:k])^2 = d^2[K:K_{n-1}]^2.
$$
These two quantities will be equal if and only if $d = d^2,$ which is true if and only if $d = 1.$